# JDBC Database Connection Failed

Tags: jaspersoft-studio, sqljdbc

For database i am using msql server express and Microsoft sql server management studio.
for reporting i am using Jaspersoft studio.for connection of database i used SQL JDBC driver,all drivers are installed but still connection of database showing failed.
[image]

[image]

Error details

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver cannot be found by net.sf.jasperreports_6.6.0.final
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.getConnection(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:173)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:128)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:122)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.runOperations(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:155)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.utils.jobs.CheckedRunnableWithProgress$1.run(CheckedRunnableWithProgress.java:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver cannot be found by net.sf.jasperreports_6.6.0.final
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:174)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.getConnection(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:145)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I setup an InterSystems Cache Data Source in Jaspersoft Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435233/how-do-i-setup-an-intersystems-cache-data-source-in-jaspersoft-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer

1. enable the sql server authentication for that refer below video
   [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qINbmzRQh1o)

2.then open jaspersoft studio and simply select JDBC driver and add sql server authentication username and password

and here you are done!!!

Comment: My SQL Server is ADMIN\MSSQLSERVER01. What should I input into JDBC url?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the following error:
[image]

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'login_hsd_report'.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:126)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:120)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.runOperations(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:154)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.utils.jobs.CheckedRunnableWithProgress$1.run(CheckedRunnableWithProgress.java:51)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'login_hsd_report'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2894)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2334)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:614)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:356)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:185)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.getConnection(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:164)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:124)
    ... 4 more
```

Despite having verified the following information:

- Have the correct java and JDBC Driver version
- Have the TCP port of the SQL server open enabled
- Correct credentials in SQL Server

I kept getting the same error, my mistake was that I had not enabled SQL Server authentication, by following @Mayur Satav recommendation, Jasper managed to connect

[image]